# matplotlib documentation in html format

Tags: python, html, documentation, matplotlib, offline

I like the matplotlib documentation at this web address,

http://matplotlib.org/index.html

but I cannot access it when my laptop computer is offline (traveling, etc.)

Can anyone recommend a way to download the html docs for matplotlib?
This is possible for the python docs.

Thanks.
Bill

Comment: You can build the html yourself if you download the source and all the right tools.  Of course the PDF is available for immediate download...

Comment: OK.  I found initial instructions here.  http://matplotlib.org/devel/documenting_mpl.html

Comment: @user1579230 You should answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **whole** matplotlib.org website is stored in a github repository. You can download the whole thing from:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.github.com

(direct zip link: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.github.com/archive/master.zip)

The result will probably be a pretty big zip file. Alternatively, as others have said, you can build the documentation yourself by following:

http://matplotlib.org/devel/documenting_mpl.html

HTH

Answer (score 2):

The Documentation is available as a PDF for download at:
http://matplotlib.org/Matplotlib.pdf

Comment: perfect and simple. google searches don't find this.